# Exists a bounded linear operator with this two conditions

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Show that there exists a bounded linear operator
$$T:L^p((0,\infty))\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ such that the following conditions hold:

a.) $||T||_*=1$

b.)if $u$ is polynomial of degree at most one, then $Tu=u'(0)$

My thoughts:
At first,I thought anything like $$Tu=\int_0^1 u(x)dx$$
But I have problems with finding the operator due to the second condition.

Comment: the second condition is strange because polynomials aren't in $L^p (0,\infty)$

Comment: So you mean that the execise doesn't have a solution?

Comment: I don't know, I just find it strange that the operator is applied to something it is not defined for a priori.

Comment: What if we look at $L^1((-1,1))$?